# Getting out of scope error with dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am getting an out of scope error in my copy function, when I try to copy the contents of the first array into the DMA one. The try-catch block is required.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void show( const int a[], unsigned elements );
int * copy( const int a[], unsigned els );
void die(const string & msg);

int main()
{


    int arr[4] = {4, 2, 3, 6};
    show(arr, 4);
    int * newArr = copy(arr, 4);

}

void show( const int a[], unsigned elements )
{

    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        cout << a[i] << endl;

}

int * copy( const int a[], unsigned els )
{

    try
    {
        int * newArr = new int[els];
    }
    catch(const bad_alloc &)
    {
        die("Alloc Failure");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < els; i++)
        newArr[i] = a[i];

    return newArr;
}

void die(const string & msg)
{

    cerr << "Fatal error: " << msg << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

Comment: Simply move the code that follows the catch block into the try; you'll need to return 0/nullptr from within the catch since the compiler doesn't know it's exiting (ugh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the variable inside the `try` block then it's only accessible there. You can work around this by moving the declaration outside of the block.

```
int *newArr;

try
{
    newArr = new int[els];
}
catch(const bad_alloc &)
{
    die("Alloc Failure");
}

for (int i = 0; i < els; i++)
    newArr[i] = a[i];
```

Or by moving the rest of the code inside the `try`.

```
try
{
    int *newArr = new int[els];

    for (int i = 0; i < els; i++)
        newArr[i] = a[i];

    return newArr;
}
catch(const bad_alloc &)
{
    die("Alloc Failure");
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped. I wish I could give "best answer" to all of you. Nevertheless, I have given +1's to everyone who has participated.

Answer (score 2):

Define new array before the try, otherwise it is only defined inside the try block.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of exceptions is that you do *not* need to handle all conceivable errors right at the point where they happen, but rather in places of your choice where you are able to respond to them meaningfully. So be generous with the size of your `try` blocks:

```
int * copy(const int a[], unsigned els)
{
    try
    {
        int * newArr = new int[els];

        for (int i = 0; i < els; i++)
            newArr[i] = a[i];

        return newArr;
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc &)
    {
        die("Alloc Failure");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to

```
int * copy( const int a[], unsigned els ) {    
    int * newArr = nullptr;
    try {
        newArr = new int[els];
    }
    catch(const bad_alloc &) {
        die("Alloc Failure");
    }

    if(newArr) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < els; i++)
             newArr[i] = a[i];
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

to overcome your problem. Just initialize `newArr` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your Copy-Function is, that the new Array is a local Variable. When you than return it to the caller, the pointer adresses aren't the right ones.

You might better use two arrays which you pass as Referneces into the copy-function, like this:

```
int& copy(int& newArray, const int& oldArray) { ... }
```

Here you get a discription about references in c++ if you don't know what they supposed to be: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29